# Where are BitRay2 save games stored?

Tags: bitray2

I am trying to migrate my save games to a new laptop, but unfortunately Steam Cloud is not supported. Running a backup of the game through steam and opening this on another computer does not work either.

In the options of [BitRay2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/512450/) there is only the possibility to clear saved data, but not copy it.

Where are the save games located?

Answer (score 1):

BitRay2 uses the registry to save certain information, including save games.

In `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\DefaultCompany\BITRAY2` you can find a key named `BITRAY2_LevelCount_h41656808`. This stores the number of levels unlocked.

Copying the value from the computer which contains your latest progress to the computer where you want to reload your progress does the trick!